# Compiling Java sources with Clojure deps.edn

Tags: java, clojure, compilation

How do I configure my Clojure CLI `deps.edn` file to compile Java source files along with my `.clj` Clojure source files?

I found [badigeon](https://github.com/EwenG/badigeon) which can compile Java sources, but I'm struggling to use in my simple project.

Answer (score 3):

You can now do that with [clojure.tools.build](https://clojure.org/guides/tools_build#_mixed_java_clojure_build)

Comment: This page was the highest ranked answer via $SEARCH_ENGINE, but this is probably a good example, so adding it here: https://github.com/seancorfield/java-clojure-example/tree/master

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your context ...

The "best" way to do this currently, is to separate your Java and Clojure sources into two projects.  In the Java project, create a jar with the compiled classes (using standard Java tools - perhaps `make` and `javac`) and install the jar into your local maven repo. Then add the jar file as a dependency in the `deps.edn` of your Clojure project.

You might also be able to use the jar directly, without installing locally, by using the `local/root` feature in `deps.edn`.  See the [Deps Rationale](https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli) for how to do that.

Another way would be to arrange to have the Java sources compiled into a `classes` sub-directory of your combined (Java / Clojure) project and then add the `classes` directory to the `:paths` key in your `deps.edn`. The creation of the class files will (again) have to be done with Java tools or shell scripts - outside of `clj`.

There are some recent developments in `clj` that may make this easier in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`clj` will not do that.

`lein` do a lot of things that are out-of-scope for `clj` command line.

You may find some library that do that, then you can call `clj -m lib-that-compiles-java`